# Getting started with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, frameworks

I'm working on my project and i used alot of js and jquery  in that project and now it's alot messy over here. 
I was suggested to move over to some js framework so i started working on backbone.js. I need your guyz help on how i can learn it fast enough as afterwards i've to shift my code in this framework too. I'm beginner in this framework so any suggestion for tutorials or books i can speedily go through and learn it ? Also backbone.js is my only option because i've to use it in further projects as well.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Rao!  [Open ended questions like this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) tend to be discouraged, since they can't really be completely answered.  Have you checked out http://backbonejs.org?  It's quite exhaustive and has links to examples and tutorials.

Comment: @brad yes i checked it but i'm not getting where to start from this site. that's why i was asking for a bit easy  or simple tutorial or book.

Comment: Did you check the ["list of tutorials" link](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/wiki/Tutorials%2C-blog-posts-and-example-sites) in the second paragraph?

Comment: Did you even read the doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should start by reading the **[Backbone.js book](http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/) by Addy Osmani**. If you are familiar with the MVC design pattern then you may start directly from **The Internals** to get yourself started quickly. Now, after getting a feel of what is possible with Backbone.js, you should try to understand the code of the very simple [todo app](http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/backbone/) which has its [source code](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc/tree/gh-pages/architecture-examples/backbone) in Github. Try to understand every part of the code - I found it very insightful as I was only beginning javascript and the concepts were new. Some parts of the **todo app** is explained in the book mentioned above, but some other parts you have to figure out on your own. You will need the help of [official documentation](http://backbonejs.org/). Figure out how to code nested models and views.

Once you have done this, get your hands dirty by starting coding an application. This will give rise to many questions. Now, you have to take help of the documentation, stackoverflow and the #documentcloud, #javascript and #jquery IRC channels when you get stuck.

Most importantly - **have fun**!